# What is the cause of getting this error when creating a new Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions

I created a C# Blob Trigger Function. It generated this code by default:

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

and immediately was presented the following error in a red popup.

> Error:   Function ($BlobTriggerCSharp1) Error:
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'Functions.BlobTriggerCSharp1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot
>   bind parameter 'name' to type String. Make sure the parameter Type is
>   supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g.
>   ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
>   method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Answer (score 9):

Fix was to change the Path setting in "Integrate" to have an appended "/{name}"

Comment: Yes, you can change that path template as you need to. You could also just remove the {name} expression if you don't need it (removing the corresponding method param).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a mismatch between the `/{name}` and the actual method parameter name (I'd renamed it to `blobName` without thinking, but not updated the template to match).

Once I used the same in both places i.e. `name` (or `blobName`), it worked.